# CentOS, it's unbelievable about yum-config-manager

Tags: centos, centos6, yum

[image]

the figure shows that I have installed the `yum-utils`, but I also could not use the command `yum-config-manager`.
On writing the command `yum-config-manager` it is showing `yum-config-manager: command not found`.

The output of the following command
`yum search yum-config-manager`

It is showing

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.vpsnet.com
 * epel: mirror.vpsnet.com
 * extras: mirror.vpsnet.com
 * remi-safe: mirror.23media.de
 * updates: mirror.vpsnet.com
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
========================= Matched: yum-config-manager ==========================
remi-release.noarch : Configuration de YUM pour le d?p?t remi
yum-utils.noarch : Utilities based around the yum package manager
```

How can I use `yum-config-manager` in this scenario?

Comment: Which version of CentOS are you using? I have `yum-utils-1.1.30-40.el6.noarch` which provides `yum-config-manager`

Comment: centos5.5，it is too old( •̅_•̅ )

Comment: Its is too old and *unsupported*. I've just checked one of my old boxes and nop - same problem as you. Any reason you can't update?

Comment: Yeah i had changed the system to ubuntu, thanks for your comment

Comment: No worries - if you have everything working now it might be an idea to delete this question since it no longer applies :)

Comment: Another question. Do you have any idea about file system built in single server? What kind of FS could be chosen?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - sorry What are you trying to do/find out?

Comment: File storage database, which one maybe easy to use?

Comment: Can't really help as I still don't fully understand what your asking... Delete this question and head over to https://www.superuser.com - you may get more assistance over there since it sounds like your having general setup issues rather than programming issues which is what this forum is for.

Comment: I have the same issue, so this question is not supposed to be deleted.